# Least Squares Regression in Stata

Tags: regression, negative-binomial-distribution

Can anyone explain how Stata computes the least squares parameters with a single explanatory variable - what algorithm Stats uses to compute the parameters.

Actually I want to understand  the computational algorithm of negative binomial regression model.

Comment: Negative binomial regression in Stata has precisely zero to do with least squares. The code for `nbreg` is accessible to you, assuming that you use Stata, and the manual documentation for `nbreg` is online at www.stata.com/manuals13/rnbreg.pdf even if you don't use Stata. If you think that negative binomial regression is based on least squares, it is not clear that you will understand any explanation any way; you need to learn more basic stuff first.

Answer (score 3):

Your question makes the mistaken assumption that negative binomial regression uses least squares. This is not the case.

Least squares, as used in ordinary regression ($y=X\beta+\epsilon$), estimates the parameters, $\beta$, by minimizing the sum of squared residuals; this leads to solving the normal equations:

$$X'X\,\hat \beta = X'y$$

to obtain $\hat \beta $.

In almost any statistics package, negative binomial regression would normally be estimated by maximizing the likelihood ([MLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood)), not by least squares.

In the case of `nbreg`, Nick Cox's link in comments does lead you to the information for Stata (though you have to follow a series of links from that document through one or two other documents).

To be specific (since I doubt you will have the expertise to find the information in a document like the one Nick is pointing to), `nbreg` -as one would have anticipated - finds the parameters by [maximum likelihood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood). It appears to achieve this by maximizing the log-likelihood, by default using a version of [Newton-Raphson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization#Higher_dimensions) with step halving, with some modifications to deal with regions where Newton-Raphson is unsuitable.

This is an iterative method: it starts at some 'guess' at the parameter estimates and uses the first and second derivatives of the log-likelihood there to guess where the maximum might be (if the likelihood surface were Gaussian, as it should be asymptotically, this guess would go directly to the optimum). The same information is then calculated at the new point to form a new (normally much better) guess, until the value can't be improved further.

The variance-covariance matrix of parameters estimates can then be approximately calculated from the Hessian matrix at the optimum ($H$ in the last of the above links).